# When a Brawler dies in Brawl Ball, where does his ball go?

Tags: brawl-stars

When a Brawler is defeated in Brawl Ball while holding the ball, the ball doesn't just stay in place. It bounces around in a range of about one tile in a seemingly random direction.

Is the direction random? It seems random most of the time, but I feel like the ball really likes to score points when it falls out of a Brawler's hand close to the goal line, which makes me think the direction can be affected by something.